# Copying data from/to excel worksheet using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that is suppose to copy data from an excel file I receive in a email and paste it to another file on the row that has the same date. When I try and run the macro it says there is an error. Can anyone look at my code and direct me as to where my error is. I am fairly new to coding and creating macros.

```
Sub CopyDataToPlan()

Dim LDate As String
Dim LColumn As Integer
Dim LFound As Boolean
Dim WS As Worksheet


On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Set WS = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls").Sheets("McKinney")


'Retrieve date value to search for
WS = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls").Cell("B15").Value

Sheets("Input").Select

'Start at column B
LColumn = 2
LFound = False

While LFound = False

    'Encountered blank cell in row 2, terminate search
    If Len(Cells(2, LColumn)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching date was found."
        Exit Sub

    'Found match in row 2
    ElseIf Cells(2, LColumn) = LDate Then

        'Select values to copy from "McKinney" sheet
        Sheets("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls").Select
        Range("C15:I15").Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste onto "Key Indicator" sheet
        Sheets("Input").Select
        Cells(3, LColumn).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

        LFound = True
        MsgBox "The data has been successfully copied."

    'Continue searching
    Else
        LColumn = LColumn + 1
    End If

Wend

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the "On Error GoTo Err_Execute" because it is masking the real error. Then post the real error code and description

Comment: I changed WS = Workbooks.... to LDate = Workbooks. It says object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: LDate = Worksheets("McKinney1").Range("b15").Value ... without the SET

Comment: Now i get a subscript out of range message

Comment: Use Option Explicit and do not try to set the same variable (WS) to two different types of data (worksheet and date).

Comment: Cross post. Subscript out of range is to do with arrays and ranges and referring to an item not contained by the array.

Answer (score 0):

What line generates the error? It seems that your variable LDate never recieves a date. May be instead of

```
WS = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls").Cell("B15").Value
```

you meant to write

```
LDate = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls").Cell("B15").Value
```

All this looks like pretty lenghty and dangerous code: why not a) get both the date from your input sheet and the data you want to copy (looks like you could put these in an array with a for loop) and then b) search for the cell that contains the date you want (1 statement) to retrieve the row of the cell that matches the date you want, and then c) loop the data from the array to the sheet.

Comment: @user 471807...can you give me an example of what that code would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Be more explicit with references .  The code runs faster and is easier to debug:

```
Sub CopyDataToPlan()
Dim LDate As String
Dim LColumn As Integer
Dim LFound As Boolean
Dim WkbCensus As workbook
Dim WksCensus As worksheet
Dim WkbThis As workbook
Dim WksInput As worksheet

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Set WkbThis = thisworkbook
Set wksInput = WkbMe.Sheets("Input")
Set WkbCensus = Workbooks("McKinney Daily Census Template OCT 10.xls")
Set WksCensus = Wkb.Sheets("McKinney")

LDate = WksCensus.Cell("B15").Value

LColumn = 2
LFound = False

While LFound = False
    If Len(wksInput.cells(2, LColumn)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching date was found."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf wksInput.cells(2, LColumn) = LDate Then
        WksCensus.Range("C15:I15").copy
        wksInput.cells(3, LColumn).pastespecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        LFound = True
        MsgBox "The data has been successfully copied."
    Else
        LColumn = LColumn + 1
    End If
Wend

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
     MsgBox "An error occurred."
 End Sub
```